# Passing position of variadic template argument

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I would like to create a function that takes a variable number of template arguments. Later with these arguments the function should pass their position like this:

```
template<typename R, typename Args...>
R myFunction(Data &data, void *function) {
    auto f = (R (*)(Args...))function;
    return f(read<Args1>(data, 1), read<Args2>(data, 2), ...);// <-- This is the problem
}
```

The given code is of course not compilable. Is there any way to fix it? Is there a way to do it without variadic templates without too much code duplication?

Comment: I'm sure you can avoid the object-pointer to function-pointer cast.

Comment: @sellibitze: Is that a problem? Because I can only have a void* pointer user data that are passed from a C function.

Comment: The data can be a `void *`.  It's the function being a `void *` that is a concern.

Comment: @JurajBlaho: This kind of cast ist highly non-portable. I suggest you explain what problem you intend to solve like that. Chances are that you'll receive more useful answers if you do. It seems to me, we have a bit of an X/Y problem.

Comment: @sellibitze: Thanks for the comment, now I see that casting function pointer to `void*` is UB. I will have to solve it a bit differently, but I am still able to solve the problem using ideas from the accepted answer.

Comment: Instead of using a `void*` for the `function` argument, I would have added another template parameter for the function type, then the typecast is not needed.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: This function itself is easy to do right. But the C API I have to use can only store `void*` data. I will have to wrap the function pointer in a `struct`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, that is possible:

```
// we need a compile-time helper to generate indices
template< std::size_t... Ns >
struct indices
{
  typedef indices< Ns..., sizeof...( Ns ) > next;
};

template< std::size_t N >
struct make_indices
{
  typedef typename make_indices< N - 1 >::type::next type;
};

template<>
struct make_indices< 0 >
{
  typedef indices<> type;
};
```

With these helpers, you need one forwarder for your function like this:

```
template<typename R, typename... Args, std::size_t... Ns>
R myFunctionImpl(void *Data, void *function, indices<Ns...> ) {
    auto f = (R (*)(Args...))function;
    return f(read<Args>(Data, Ns + 1)...);// +1 because indices is zero-based
}

template<typename R, typename... Args>
R myFunction(void *Data, void *function) {
   return myFunctionImpl< R, Args... >( Data, function, typename make_indices<sizeof...(Args)>::type() );
}
```

**EDIT:** How does it work? First, we determine the size of the [argument pack](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) `Args` through [`sizeof...`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof...). `make_indices<N>::type` then expands into `indices<0,1,2,...,N-1>`. It is given as an additional parameter to the implementation function (from the forwarder who just creates a dummy instance), hence argument deduction kicks in on the implementation function's side and puts the generated indices into the argument pack `Ns`.

The implementation function now has two argument packs with the same size, namely `Args` and `Ns`. When expanded through the ellipsis `...`, the ellipsis expands the *whole expression* that it's applied to and it expands all parameter packs in parallel! In the above example that expression is `read<Args>(Data, Ns+1)`, which nicely expands into the OPs pseudo-code.

Comment: can you post a simple example?

Comment: I just did. What is missing from the example I gave?

Comment: What is missing is a real example. With `main()` and some functions (with 1,2,3 parameters). How do you use these functions and structures?

Comment: It took me some time to fully understand the code and it seems that it should work.

Comment: I still don't get it. How this: `typename make_indices<sizeof...(Args)>::type()` compiles? Should be a compilation error.

Comment: It's a well known technique and it does compile. I added a small explanation to my answer.